# Why does building something on a tile modifies the profit of it?

Tags: civilization-5

I have just started playing Civ 5 and I'm confused regarding the tiles.

When you built a city you get an amount of tiles around it, and when your population increases you get to assign a citizen to work in each tile. When you get workers you can build on the tiles, however when i try to build on a tile that is being worked on i get a notification that the profit is going to be modified or something like that......

What does this mean?. If i for example modify a tile that is being worked on and build a Plantation does it mean that the profit out of it will low?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this means is simply what it says, when you build on a tile, the benefits you get from working it may change.

Different improvements give different rewards, as do different "raw tiles".

Sometimes, building an improvement on a tile may have a negative impact on some output (production, gold, culture, religion). An example is building a Plantation on Bananas, which will provide *-1 Production* along with the *+2 Gold*, or entirely swap one output with another.

The alert you get is merely to make sure you're aware that there's a possibility things will change and not necessarily in the way that's best for your glorious Empire.

Comment: Then it is recommended to build on a tile?

Comment: Yes. The improvements are 99.9% of the time a benefit.

Comment: Ok i will try later.... can i add you in steam :)?

Comment: Is this a typo? "Sometimes, building a *plantation* may have..." Did you mean "building an improvement" ?